# Magento 2 : Which event will trigger when a Navbar Item is clicked?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, navigation

I've done some searching around and i'm trying to find the observed event for when a particular navbar item is clicked.

The goal is to run some code for whenever that navbar item is selected but I do not want this piece of code to run on the other navbar items. Is an observer the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: There is no magento events for a DOM element action, you should try javascript to achieve this may be with ajax call when an element is clicked and so.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. I will give that a go instead cheers for the fast response. -A

Comment: You're welcome :)